# Scala 2.8 - Potential problem with named arguments

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, named-parameters

Consider the following code :

```
// My code
class Person(var age: Int)

// Client's code
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val p = new Person(age = 18)
    println(p.age)
  }
}
```

Now say later I need to define an accessor method for the `age` field.

However trying to do something like below isn't legal as field names and method names share the same namespace in Scala :

```
// *** DOES NOT COMPILE ***
// My code
class Person(age: Int) {
  def age = /* some code that gives integer */
}

// Client's code
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val p = new Person(age = 18)
    println(p.age)
  }
}
```

So I need to rename either the constructor argument `age` or my field `age`. Either way I will be breaking the client code, isn't it?

Is there any possible work around this? Or is this an inherent problem with named arguments?

Please shed some light on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The second code block *does* compile, provided you put something in place of the `/* some code that gives integer */` placeholder comment.